# __proto__ of a function

Tags: javascript

If I have a class called Person.

```
var Person =  function(fname, lname){
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
}

Person.prototype.mname = "Test";
var p = new Person('Alice','Bob');
```

Now, `p.__proto__` refers to prototype of Person but, when I try to do `Person.__proto__`, it points to `function()`, and `Person.constructor` points to `Function()`.

Can someone explain what is the difference between `function()` and `Function()` and why the prototype of a `Function()` class is a `function()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain what is the difference between function()  and Function() and why the prototype of a Function()  class is a function()?

`__proto__` is an implementation-detail exposing the [[prototype]]. The [[prototype]] and the constructor need not be (are often not) the same thing. Anyway...

Consider this hypothesis: **It is an impl. detail that depends on the engine** -- and in the particular engine tested (FF, which version?), Function is an object which itself has a [[prototype]] of function. function is the primitive function-object. Person.prototype is (by default) of type function (the primitive function-object) and the assertions stated as a result of this apparent dichotomy. (JS has some quirks: `new Number(0)` is not the same as `0`.)

However, this is not the case in IE(8). In IE the default prototype is a "plain object", not a function-object.

Answer (score 1):

When defining a function like this:

```
var Person = function (fname, lname){
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
}
```

This will make `Person` a function.  A function is an object, which needs to be constructed like any other 'first class' object, so it has a constructor: the constructor of all function objects, called `Function`.

The prototype of all functions appears to be an object called `function`.

I like to refer to a nice [explanation by Mike Koss](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm) that learned me a lot.

Comment: Hey, I don't agree with Mike Koss. He has stated that, constructor property is part of the newly created object. "Note that in addition to the x and y properties that we created, our object has an additional property called constructor that points (in this case) to an internal JavaScript function." I think constructor property is not part of the newly created object. It is found by following person.__proto__.constructor. So if I redirect person.__prototype__ to null, then this person object will never be able to find its constructor.

Comment: The article also mentioned that the `__proto__` field is not standard ecmascript, yet the `object.constructor` property seems to be standardized (cfr http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_constructor_boolean.asp)